# Sigmoid function with separate control of derivative at 0 and sharpness of bend.

Tags: functions, interpolation, data-analysis

For a physical relationship, $f(x)$, I'm trying to model, i have a fairly good determination of some of the boundaries, such that

$ f(0) = 0$

$f'(0) = B$

$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f = A $

So far, what I have is:

$ f(x) = A \tanh(b x)$

This fulfills the requirements listed. But one thing that is not known until data becomes available, is how fast f approaches A. So I have narrowed my needs down to that I need a Sigmoid function, that will allow me to vary the rate of convergence to the upper asymptote independently of the derivative at zero.

[Wikipedia has an illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGjl-t%28x%29.svg) of what I need - but rather than a discrete set of functions, I need to vary the curvature with a parameter.

Please give suggestions for closed form solutions that satisfy these requirements.

/AdamAL - an engineer with a math problem

**Edit** The function does not need to be true Sigmoid. Fulfilling the requirements for $x>0 $ is sufficient. However, sharpness of bend parameter $c\to\infty$, the solution should tend to the piecewise linear given by,  f=$Bx$ and $f=A$, respectively

Comment: Use something like $A \tanh^a b x$ perhaps?

Comment: I've considered that, but $\frac{\text{d}\tanh(x)^a}{\text{d}x} = 0$ for $a>1$, it seems.

Comment: ... at $x=0$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am the best to answer something like this.

Will you need the function to be [symmetrical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) for negative $x$ values, because you don't give any conditions for that? In oher words, *must* this be a sigmoid function?

Otherwise, maybe you can multiply the function you have by some factor, like:

$$f(x) = A \tanh (bx)(1-xe^{-cx})$$

It should be OK at the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=+\infty$ because:

- the extra factor cannot change the fact that $f(0)=0$,
- the rule for the [derivative of a product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) gives an unchanged $f'(0)$ value compared to that of your function since the new factor evaluated at $x=0$ is $1$, and the second term from the product rule (Leibniz) is already $0$ because $\tanh$ is zero.
- $f(+\infty)$ is still $A$ because the new factor converges to $1$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Then you can use the new parameter $c$ to control how fast the convergence towards the horizontal asymptote is.

However, I cannot "justify" just why I chose this specific "correction" factor, and other approaches would certainly have worked too.

And as I indicated, now $f$ is no longer a sigmoid function if you consider also the domain $x<0$.

Maybe someone else will come up with a more "motivated" or even simpler family of functions? Depending on the physics, some other function might be more natural, I don't know.

**Edit:** If you want nice behavior for negative $x$, I guess you can just make the new factor an even function of $x$, so:

$$f(x) = A \tanh (bx)(1-x^2e^{-cx^2})$$

Comment: Thank you for this, jsn. Your valuable time is greatly appreciated :) . The negative behavior is not relevant to the problem. As a bonus, as best I can tell, your solution does not change the monotonicity of the derivative, which is probably an additional requirement for a good solution. The only thin missing, would be if the extra factor would disappear for some value of c (like 0 or 1). Changing to $..cxe^{..}$ changes makes the derivative non-monotonous.

Comment: Upon application, I realize, that this solution is not sufficient. While the factor allows to soften the bend, it tends to 1 for higher $c$, and so it cannot increase the sharpness beyond that given by tanh(bx). I'm revoking the correct answer in case that can motivate other answers.

Comment: @AdamAL You are right. My factor $(1-xe^{-cx})$ is only relevant "in the middle", far from $x=0$ and far from $x=+\infty$. Since it approaches $1$ very fast (in fact exponentially), it is negligible for high values of $x$, so it doesn't change the rate at which $f(x)$ tends to $A$ asymptotically (for very high values of $x$).